# How to back String from UUID in node-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cassandra

Using [express-cassandra](http://express-cassandra.readthedocs.io/en/stable/datatypes/#datatypes-and-utility-functions) i am generating an uuid by `uuidFromString()` method. Is there any way to back it to its previous form.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, just use the `toString()` method on the `Uuid` object you generated. For example:

```
var myUuid = Uuid.fromString('ce547c40-acf9-11e6-80f5-76304dec7eb7');
var myUuidString = myUuid.toString();
```

Since express-cassandra is just using the DataStax driver under the covers, you can see the `Uuid` docs here:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/nodejs/3.0/module-types-Uuid.html

Comment: actually it doesn't work , say i have string = 'hello' , to save in cqlsh i am using models.uuidFromString('hello') . Now its an uuid , how to unparse this to 'hello'